# Populating form fields in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, sqlite

I am trying to populate my form fields with AJAX when a request is being made. I was able to successfully made the request and fetched data, but the issue I am facing is that the input fields are not being populated.

If I populate the return data into a div it will display but not displaying in a form fields.

My HTML code

```
<form id="fm" method="post"  novalidate>
<div style="margin-bottom:10px">
<input class="easyui-textbox" name="descr" id="descr"  multiline="true" data-options="label:'Description:'" style="width:100%;">
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom:10px">
<input class="easyui-textbox" name="unit" id="unti" style="width:100%"  data-options="label:'Unit:'">
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom:10px">
<input class="easyui-numberbox" name="rate" id="rate" style="width:100%"  data-options="label:'Rate:'">
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom:10px">
<input class="easyui-numberbox" name="fixing" id="fixing" style="width:100%"  data-options="label:'Fixing:'">
</div>
<div style="margin-bottom:10px">
<input class="easyui-numberbox" name="quantity" id="quantity" style="width:100%"  data-options="label:'Quantity:'">
</div>
</form>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
function load_click(param)
{

    var resp = $("#loadstatus");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "boqs/load.php",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){
            resp.html(' <img src="../assets/img/rot_small.gif" />');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (Array.isArray(data) && data.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                  //for each   value in the json response
                    $(".descr").val(data[i].descr);
                    $(".unit").val(data[i].unit);
                    $(".rate").val(data[i].rate);
                    $(".fixing").val(data[i].fixing);
                    $(".quantity").val(data[i].quantity);
                    //alert(data[i].descr);
                } // for
                resp.html('');
            } 
         });
        }
```

PHP source code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bill_preparation ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$ret2 = $db->query($sql);

$json_resp = array();


while($row = $ret2->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
    $json_array['descr'] = $row['descr'];
    $json_array['unit'] = $row['unit'];
    $json_array['rate'] =  $row['rate'];
    $json_array['fixing'] = $row['fixing'];
    $json_array['quantity'] =  $row['quantity'];
    //$json_array['amount'] =  $row['amount'];

    array_push($json_resp, $json_array);
}
//$result["rows"] = $items;

echo json_encode($json_resp, true);
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Your javascript function is not complete, its missing some closing `)` and `}` and therefore wont compile?

Comment: If your query can only ever return ONE ROW **`LIMIT 1`** then you dont need a while loop to process the resultset !!

Comment: `json_encode()` **does not** have a second parameter that can be set to `true`

Comment: please share your HTML

Comment: Might also want to change your selector from class to id: `$(".descr")` to `$("#descr")` for ex.

Comment: And as there is only one object returned then you dont need the for loop in the javascript eiterh

Comment: @IncredibleHat, I did but still nothing.

Comment: Since you are using easyui, you might need to use the `setText()` and `setValue()` methods.  [Documentation Here](https://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/textbox.php).

Comment: @PatrickQ,  I did this: $(".descr").setValue(data[i].descr); but still nothing.

Comment: @OlajumokeAdemilade Did you notice that I mentioned two methods?

Comment: @PatrickQ, Thanks. I did this: $(".descr").textbox('setValue',data[i].descr); and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to very one for your support. @Patrick suggestion pointed me to the right direction.

I discovered using `$(".descr").val(data[i].descr);` doesn't work in **easyui** form so I used `$(".descr").textbox('setValue',data[i].descr);` which worked.

I hope this help someone working with **easyui**.

Comment: Sounds like easyui isn't so easy afterall ;) I've never seen such a convoluted way to simply set a form element by ID before.